# Sequence to Sequence models only returning the same response?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language, lstm

I've tried out my code just to make sure it works on a dataset of 100 input and output sentences. Turns out that no matter what I insert, the trained model only responds with either 1 of 2 phrases.

I convert the sentences into one-hot vectors, and my matrix is very sparce, in other words, I have some very long sentences and some very short ones, and the short ones are padded with zero vectors. I also do not implement attention and beam search.

Is this because of the incredibly small dataset, or does that normally not occur?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without seeing the data and running reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like small and biased dataset to me, which assigns high biases to those 2 neurons on output layer. Take a look at the biases in the last layer.